# Что обозначает код [_=&*+[]{}](){}()?

Tags: c++, задание-на-собеседовании

```
int main(void) { 
    [_=&*+[]{}](){}();
}
```

Как расшифровать этот код?

Comment: Вызов лямбда-функции...

Comment: а внутрь передается ещё одна.

Comment: @Harry, начало и конец понятно, а в середине что? `&*+[]{}`

Comment: @KoVadim Скорее захватывается :)

Comment: @KoVadim, ну я могу предположить, что на лямбде можно использовать унарный плюс, разыменование и взятие адреса, но разве ей круглые скобки не нужны?

Comment: @Qwertiy да вроде не нужны, если от `void`?

Comment: а что компилятор ругается на этот код? :)

Comment: @Zhihar, так компилятору всё норм: https://ideone.com/2dy3Hb.

Comment: `auto x = [_=&*+[]{}](){
        cout << typeid(_).name() << endl;
    };
    x();
    cout << typeid(x).name() << endl;` дает в VC++ `void (__cdecl*)(void)` и ```class `int __cdecl main(void)'::`2'::<lambda_2>```.

Comment: @Qwertiy О круглых скобках - https://ideone.com/FbujxA

Comment: у меня в VS вывалилось

`C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '{' 
C2337 '_': attribute not found
C2059 syntax error: ')'
C2059 syntax error: '<default int type>'`

Comment: @Harry, я тебе форматирование коммента правильно исправил или накосячил?

Comment: @Zhihar Версия VC++? и 17, и 19 нормально отрабатывают.

Comment: @Zhihar, возможно, какая-то у тебя старая VS...

Comment: потому что используется синтаксис, который с 14 плюсов появился.

Comment: в том то и дело, что 2017 (15.9.26)

Comment: ну так это студия. тут стандарт ещё нужно принудительно включить в настройках.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Давайте перепишем это так

```
( // для красоты
    [
        _ = &*+[]{}
    ](){}
) // для красоты
(); // вызываем лямбду
```

Теперь все будет понятно, кроме содержимого квадратных скобок - `_ = &*+[]{}`. Этот [синтаксис появился с 14 плюсов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Lambda_capture_expressions). Здесь подчеркивание - это имя переменной (как не удивительно). А справа от равно - функция. [Плюсик делает с лямбды обычную функцию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this). Ну а звездочка и амперсанд взаимно уничтожаются. Неверится? Перепишите вот так

```
(
    [
        _ = &*+[]{}
    ](){std::cout << typeid(_).name();}
)
();
```

И в случае gcc увидите `PFvvE`, что значит `void (*)()`

Ну что, я взят?

Comment: *Ну что, я взят?* Overqualified! :)  А всерьез - как этот плюс делает функцию? Т.е. я вижу, что да, но что-то не соображу, почему...

Comment: ну так на техлида вопрошающих, естественно. Ну что бы им объяснить, что и как надо делать.

Comment: @Harry - добавил в ответ ссылку по поводу плюса

Comment: А ещё на javascript бочку катють xD

Comment: javascript - это простенький язык, любой начинающий с++джун даже не будет напрягаться, если что - всегда же можно в сорцах (в сорцах движка, естественно) поправить.

Comment: Спасибо. Но "Как это тонко!" (с) Анекдот...